# How to NOT generate debug information for specific source files / source sections?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to create a Debug build of our Vs2005 (C++) project and exclude specific modules or code sections from being included into the debug information? Or is there an option to have VS generate multiple PDB files from a single project?

It looks like our generated PDB file is getting too large for Visual Studio to handle/generate correctly and the result is that VS tells us that the debug symbols do not match. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

I investigate the option of splitting the project into multiple smaller projects, but I guess this will take some time. But it would be great if we could debug the current project as it is in the meantime.

Comment: I'd definitely go with splitting the project into smaller projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Andreas' comment - you're almost certainly better splitting the project.

However, if you right-click a C++ source file (don't think you can do this with C#), and open the properties you've got complete control over how that specific file (or files) is built.

K

Comment: In Visual Studio 2005, I can do this: right-click on a .cpp file, open the properties dialog, go to C/C++, General and set "Debug Information Format" to "disabled". This works, I cannot step into the code of that file anymore. 
But in Visual Studio 2010 beta2, the "disabled" option isn't available anymore.

Comment: Hmm. haven't tried out the new 2010 yet but don't like the sound of this - you should get more control, not less as time goes on in my book...